# migrate data from one table to another with parent child association

Tags: mysql, ruby-on-rails, ruby

I am migrating data from table A to table B.

Table A has fields `id`, `parent_id`,`title`, `credit`.

Table B has fields `id`, `parent_id`, `title`, `credit`. where id is auto incremental field.

Table A has self association, where `parent_id` refers to a row in Table A itself.

From a rake task I need to migrate data from table A to table B.

sample data in table A:

```
id | parent_id | title | credit

12 | nil       | ABC   | 1

13 | 12        | XYZ   | 1

14 | 12        | PQR   | 0

15 | 13        | NOP   | 1
```

after migrating data to table B, it should be like this:

```
id | parent_id | title | credit

1 | nil       | ABC   | 1

2 | 1         | XYZ   | 1

3 | 1         | PQR   | 0

4 | 2         | NOP   | 1
```

When migrating data from table A to table B using ruby script, I can update `title`, `credit` with new `id`. How can I update `parent_id`?

Thanks for the support.

Answer (score 0):

Update parent id after create. Something like this,

```
a = A.all
a.each { |v|
B.create!({parent_id: v.parent_id,title: v.title,credit: v.credit})
A.update_all({parent_id: B.last.id},{parent_id: v.parent_id})
}
```

Comment: thanks for the response, {parent_id: B.last.id} will not work for my scenario.

Answer (score 0):

I think so you need to update your ids as well.

```
table_b_obj.id = table_a_obj.id
table_b_obj.save!
table_b_obj.reload
```